# css nav menu dropdown background displays wider than set width ONLY in ie8

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, background

This is my first post and I've been researching this issue for two days now but cannot find anything similar and I'm at my wits end with it.

Everything works in all my testing except for IE8. There, my css dropdown menu has a background (set in the main menu as an image) that's wider than the set `128px` width of the main nav menu. Each link has its own background, this is a background on the whole dropdown. Even moving it over `-40px` to line up with the above links still gives me that extra width. I've tried many fixes but nothing seems to work. I'm hoping the combined expertise here can figure this out! I cannot post a picture as I don't have enough reputation here, sorry. Thanks in advance....

Here is the code in my stylesheet followed by HTML5 Code:

```css
#menu{list-style:none; font-size:12px; font-weight:600; float:left; width:100%;
  margin:0px auto;position:relative; z-index:5;text-align:center;}
#menu li{float:left; margin-right:2px; position:relative;}
#menu a {display:block; background:#202020 url('images/bgmen.jpg') repeat-x;
  width:128px; height:30px; line-height:30px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
#menu a:hover{background:#202020 url('images/bgmenlt.jpg') repeat-x; color:#000;}
/* dropdown*/
#menu ul{background:#000 url('images/bgmen.jpg') repeat-x; background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
  list-style:none; position:absolute; left:-9999px;} 
#menu ul li{padding-top:1px; float:none;}
#menu ul a{white-space:nowrap;}
#menu li:hover ul{left:-20px;}
#menu li:hover a{background:#202020 url('images/bgmenlt.jpg') repeat-x;} 
#menu li:hover ul a{background:#202020 url('images/bgmen.jpg') repeat-x;}
#menu li:hover ul li a:hover{background:#000 url('images/bgmenlt.jpg') repeat-x;}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="http://www.mywebpage.com" target="_self">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.mywebpage.com/bio.shtml" target="_self">BIO</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.mywebpage.com/news.shtml" target="_self">NEWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.mywebpage.com/gallery.shtml" target="_self">GALLERY</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">TEST</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.mywebpage.com/name1.shtml" target="_blank">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.mywebpage.com/name2.shtml" target="_blank">test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">CONNECT</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mywebpage" target="_blank"> <img src="images/fb.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt="" title="" /> Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/mywebpage" target="_blank"> <img src="images/twitter.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt="" title="" /> Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.mywebpage.com/contact.shtml" target="_self">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.mywebpage.com/char.shtml" target="_self">CHAR</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LL6QY/

Comment: we cant see your background images, can you tell us the dimension of them?

Comment: thanks for the reply. isn't it always the way that when you finally ask for help, you find the answer! I added margin:0 padding:0 to the #menu ul and the background disappeared. I had to change the hover display to move it to the right side from -20px to 20px under #menu li:hover ul

Comment: /* dropdown*/
        #menu ul{background:#000 url('images/bgmen.jpg') repeat-x;
        background:rgba(255,255,255,0); list-style:none; position:absolute;
        left:-9999px;margin:0;padding:0;} 
        #menu li:hover ul{left:20px;}

Comment: sorry i'm not used to this format for posting but the issue is solved - 2 days of time on it but coming here worked. thank you for your help!

Comment: OP - you can add your own answer to this question, and then in a day or so you will be able to accept it as the solution. Which may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding margin:0 padding:0 to the #menu ul solved the issue, and changed the position of the dropdown by altering the #menu li:hover ul as below:

```
    #menu ul{
    background:#000 url('images/bgmen.jpg') repeat-x; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0); 
    list-style:none; position:absolute; 
    left:-9999px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;} 
    #menu li:hover ul{left:20px;}
```